# tcsh and bashrc conflict

Tags: bashrc, tcsh

I'm a new user to Ubuntu and confront a problem through some process:

- There's a freeware called TDEFNODE coded with Fortran and runs under Ubuntu. So I've just installed Ubuntu 14 on a virtual drive.
- My friend compiled the program, download "gfortran" and "tcsh", and put some syntax in the .bashrc to show the shell that the program is in some folder.
- The software runs fine from the terminal and creates a lot of result files. Some of these files are used to draw some certain shapes and vectors.
- Program needs another program called GMT so I downloaded it with all packages from the Ubuntu software center.
- The real problem I encounter is that; a file which is called "td_plot". This is another file in the software folder and uses the output files and GMT software together to draw certain type of files, like .ps. A sample command is like this:

  ```
  td_plot -p map -m aaaa -obsv -calc
  ```

  And this means : Plot a map which results are in the ".aaaa" files. And show the "observation" and "calculated" vectors on this map.
- This command produce files, but files include maps without these vectors.
- As I understood, this td_plot file having commands used under "tcsh" and the misdrawing issue is about that.
- All the process I've done until here is made under bashrc.

Any ideas to run this tcsh file properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand until now, the problem is that the script is full of commands from "tcsh" shell. Scripts starts with a "#!/bin/tcsh -f", which means to run the script with the tcsh shell(which is installed).

But the problem remains the same, output files are incorrect and missing some properties.

Is there a way around to change the shell to tcsh and run this script with it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out to work with these softwares. I don't want this topic to be a dead end, so I'll simply explain the installation process. Maybe it'll be useful somehow:

1. Installation and next process seems to rely on the versions of the softwares.
2. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a VMware virtual machine(4 CPUs, 4 GB RAM).
3. Install netcdf(libnetcdf-dev) and gdal(libgdal1-dev).
4. Download GMT-4.5.14, GSHHG-GMT-2.3.4, GMT4param.txt, and install_gmt4.sh
5. Change the parameters on GMT4param.txt:
   GSHHG_ftp=n
   GSHHG_path= (installation path)
   GMT_ftp=n
   GMT_prefix= (installation path)
   GMT_delete=n
6. Install these files, using: sudo sh install_gmt4.sh GMT4param.txt
7. Add PATH of GMT to your .bashrc file.

These steps are for GMT.

For TDEFNODE:

1. Download and compile TDEFNODE.
2. Put all the files in a directory.
3. Specify the PATHs for TDEFNODE and td_plot in .bashrc
4. Install tcsh package.

Now the software runs and works with GMT. Seems no error so far.

Answer (score 0):

(using ubuntu in this installation)

at first you should download tdefnode using [This Link](https://robmccaffrey.github.io/TDEFNODE/TDEFNODE.source.20201011.tar.gz)
([README file here](https://robmccaffrey.github.io/TDEFNODE/manual/tdefnode_manual.html)) and some other apps

```
sudo apt install make
sudo apt install gcc
sudo apt install gfortan
sudo apt install gmt
sudo apt install make
sudo apt install tcsh (this one is optional I guess)
```

> remember, where ever you need .bashrc open it using `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` and where ever you want to add some thing to PATH use `sudo export PATH=$PATH:/address to file/`. for finding address of a file use `pwd`

then extract it some where like `/home/user/TDEFNODE/`
; download [this](https://robmccaffrey.github.io/TDEFNODE/README) and do the mentioned steps for installation

And for more information about PATH , read [this](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) article

then download td_plot and add these lines to .bashrc:

```
export TD_HOME=/home/asdfgh/TDEFNODE
alias tdefnode='/home/asdfgh/TDEFNODE/tdefnode'
alias td_plot='/home/asdfgh/TDEFNODE/td_plot'


PATH=/usr/bin/gmt/:"${PATH}"
PATH=/etc/gmt/:"${PATH}"
PATH=/usr/lib/gmt/:"${PATH}"
PATH=/usr/bin/X11/gmt:"${PATH}"
PATH=/usr/share/gmt/:"${PATH}"
PATH=/usr/lib/gmt/bin/:"${PATH}"
PATH=/home/asdfgh/TDEFNODE/td_plot:"${PATH}"
```

as mentioned here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365967

as I tried td_plot and tdefnode should work properly.
ask any other questions it the comment I hope to be able to help you. :)